# debug error, nbjpdastart doesn't support the nested "modulepath" element

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to debug a java code on netbeans 8.2 and JDK 1.8.131, but I keep getting this error

nbproject\build-impl.xml:1351: The following error occurred while executing this line:
nbproject\build-impl.xml:858: nbjpdastart doesn't support the nested "modulepath" element.

there's no sufficient explanation about this error when I google it,
I appreciate your help
thanks

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271443

Comment: thank you, I ve read that one before, It didnt help

Comment: Did you try removing those lines?

Comment: they didn't mention what lines exactly

Comment: but I ve found the solution , I deleted both build.xml and build-impl.xm and the debugger worked after that

Answer (score 15):

**Delete** these files from the project folder (From **Files** tab).

- build.xml
- build-imp.xml

**Restart** netbeans.

**Debug** again.

Comment: after deleting the files you need to restart Netbeans

Answer (score 4):

Just delete build-imp.xml and restart NetBeans, it will create a new one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Only build-impl.xml delete and restart Netbeans. new build-impl.xml will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.  Deleting `build-impl.xml` only and reopening the project fixed it.  Easier and faster than restarting Netbeans (of course time varies depending on the complexity of your setup).