# netbeans debug error - nbjpdastart doesn't support the nested “modulepath” element

Tags: java, debugging, build.xml, netbeans-8.2

I'm attempting to debug a Java app in NetBeans 8.2 using JDK 1.8.171.

I get the following error:

> nbproject\build-impl.xml:1351:

The following error occurred while executing this line: `nbproject\build-impl.xml:858:`, nbjpdastart doesn't support the nested "modulepath" element.

Same problem and question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615661/debug-error-nbjpdastart-doesnt-support-the-nested-modulepath-element?answertab=votes#tab-top).

In the comment thread it was suggested to remove the `build.xml` and `build-impl.xml` as a solution.

I was skeptical about the solution suggested since the `build-impl.xml` is a generated file using the build.xml file. Also, when doing a build, clean/build, run or debug netBeans will be expecting the build.xml file.

I tried the suggested solution in incremental steps. First I deleted just the generated file (build-impl.xml), but I received an error that the build-impl.xml was missing. I then tried deleting the build.xml, and got the error that the build.xml file was missing. Is there something else that needs to be done to implement a working solution?  Is there some other work around for this issue?  I am aware that there is a NetBeans Bugzilla bug#271443, but this refers to a JavaFX debugging issue. I am having this issue with a Java application (not a JavaFX app).

Comment: I have the same problem. It used to work, so I've changed something but don't know what. :(

Comment: @Sir Exotic   For some reason I couldn't edit the previous comment. Wanted to say that the removal (by renaming) of the build.xml and build-impl.xml files gave errors.